# Windows Driver Test in Visual C#

Tags: windows, driver, wdf

I am trying to create test case in C# for the WDF drivers of Smartcard devices. but i could not find the Windows driver >  Windows Driver Test template under installed Visual C#. I am using the Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Desktop. i could not even find the Windows Driver Test in online template. Any other package i need to install?

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to achieve. What driver are you trying to test?

Comment: i am developing WDF kernel drivers of smart card devices. During the development, i want to write the customized test cases. i am following the MSDN documentaion. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh454838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be running into problems because of the version of Visual Studio that you're running: VS 2013 for Windows Desktop is essentially an "Express" edition of VS put together to provide developers with a basic IDE for building Windows desktop apps for free. The Express SKU's of VS were, however, limited in their functionality and do not support add-ons and additional SDK's, project templates and/or tooling such as WDK. For that you'll likely need a Pro edition of VS.

**Note**: Microsoft has recently released [Visual Studio Community Edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs) which is a full release of VS Pro, including add-ons and extensibility, but free for non-commercial use and/or dev teams of up to 5 people. If you meet these [licensing requirements](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs#qna), then you may have more luck using VS Community Release than VS for Windows Desktop.

Comment: You are right Rich. VS 2013 express has some limitation on the Windows driver testing. I have tried with the VS community and it has worked for me. Thanks.